# How to maintain singleton dependency injection in Nuxt 3, best practices to follow here?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I've two third-party packages, Supabase, and Ghost CMS. I need to initialize both of them "somewhere" in the whole project, and just needed their instance to be exported and use it in my `server/routes/posts.get.ts` file.

What will be the best practice to do so? As my project is an enterprise level, things need to be rightly abstracted and modular.

Sample ghost init. code:

```
import GhostContentAPI from '@tryghost/content-api';

/// Need to export this "api" variable, to use this instance across the app.
const api = new GhostContentAPI({
    url: process.env.GHOST_URL ?? '',
    key: process.env.GHOST_API_KEY ?? '',
    version: 'v5.0'
});
```

Some example code will be helpful